# parallel push_back for vector of vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a large text file around 13G which the content is an edge list of a graph. Each line has two integers `u`and`v` represent the endpoint of an edge. I want to read it to a vector of vector as an adjency vector of the graph.

Then It comes to folowing code.

```c
const int N = 3328557;
vector<vector<int> >adj{N};

int main() {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("path/to/edge/list", "r");

    int u, v;
    while (fscanf(pFile, "%d%d", &u, &v) == 2) {
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        adj[v].push_back(u);
    }
    
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

It consumes about 7min. After some analysis, I find `adj[u].push_back(v)` and `adj[v].push_back(u)` consumes most time because of random address.

Then I use a two dimension array as cache. Once it's filled, I copy all the value to vector and clear it.

```c
const int N = 3328557;
const int threshold = 100;

vector<vector<int> >adj{N};
int ln[N];
int cache[N][threshold];

void write2vec(int node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ln[node]; i++)
        adj[node].push_back(cache[node][i]);
    ln[node] = 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("path/to/edge/list", "r");

    int u, v;
    while (fscanf(pFile, "%d%d", &u, &v) == 2) {
        cache[u][ln[u]++] = v;
        if (ln[u] == threshold)
            write2vec(u);
        cache[v][ln[v]++] = u;
        if (ln[v] == threshold)
            write2vec(v);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        write2vec(i);
    
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

This time it consumes 5.5 min. It's still too long. Then I think the two `push_back` in the first code can be parallelized. But I don't know how to do. And does anyone has other idea?

Thanks.

Edit.

I think the reason why my second approach is faster is addressing on vector of vector is slower. The address of vector of vector is not contiguous, so accessing `adj[u]` needs two operation, first is `adj` then `adj[u]`.

So I want to know if I can use multiprocessing to make addressing parallelized.

Comment: I doubt that parallelising the `push_back()` calls would change much, since the `fscanf()` call implicitly synchronises each loop iteration and the I/O is probably responsible for a fair amount of the elapsed time.   You might want to estimate (upper bounds for ) the sizes of the `adj[u]` and `adj[v]` and - with vectors - reserve accordingly rather than relying on reallocation/resizing being potentially in every loop iteration.

Comment: @Peter I/O consumes around 2.5 min. And I don't think resizing of vector is the bottleneck. Because I have tested `push_back` to vector of vector randomly consumes ten times more time than `push_back` ordered.

Comment: 13G is big enough that you might start to consider alternative options. But you need to take a step back and think. Clearly you're parsing this file more than once, as you can easily spend more than 7 minutes top optimize this. Is it always the same 13G? In that case it can be wise to preprocess it. E.g. normalize such that u<v and sort by u. Then while loading only pushback u->v and create the reverse mapping v->u after you're done loading.

Comment: An [alternative approach](https://godbolt.org/z/5dWs5aPYo). I have no idea how it performs. You'll have to test it on your file.

Comment: @MSalters But creating reverse mapping is also random access.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry for my description, 3328557 is the number of nodes of my graph.

Comment: @HuZhang I see - I thought it was the number of edges. I think you can forget my alternative unless you have _a lot_ of memory. I made a small test and it was horrible on my machine with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I have more than 16GB RAM. I have tested your approach, it's slow.

Comment: The second approach is faster partly because it does not do as much work. All the values in the cache at the end of the reading loop are not written to `adj`. You'll need to call `write2vec` for every entry in the cache (at least the non-empty ones).

Comment: Adding `adj[node].reserve(adj[node].size() + ln[node]);` at the start of `write2vec` should help a lot, as you'll only do one memory allocation per call (rather then potentially multiple ones; the initial flush with a full cache will typically allocate new memory and copy the existing content 10 or 11 times).

Comment: How much time does it take if you add this as the first line in `main` in your first version of the program? `for(auto& e : adj) e.reserve(287);` - It took < 2 minutes for 3328557 nodes (with ~287 connections each) for me. I just guessed 287 from the number of nodes and the size of the file.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Sorry, It's my fault. I have edited the code.

Comment: I have tried to use `reserve`, it makes no sense. So I think it's because addressing on 2D array is faster than vector of vector. @TedLyngmo @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: `reserve()` "_makes no sense_"? That sounds odd. I've always found `reserve` to improve speed when I have some idea of how many elements to reserve space for. In your case I assumed ~287 edges per node (if every node have approximately the same number of edges) - but you are saying that adding `for(auto& e : adj) e.reserve(287);` as the first thing in `main` in your first version of the program did nothing to improve the speed?

Comment: Are you free to change the format of the `list` file? I would make it a binary file instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tested `reserve` on my two computers. Both make no sense. It's confusing. And doesn't change the format of `list` file only contributes to the speed of reading file?

Comment: When you say "_make no sense_" - do you mean that it didn't improve the speed? How many edges does the node with the most edges have? Yes, changing the format of `list` to a binary format where all nodes are stored as `uint32_t` will increase the speed of reading the file - probably a lot.

Comment: Yes, it didn't improve the speed. The file contains 800M edges, Max degree of all nodes is 4000.@TedLyngmo

Answer (score 0):

"I think the two push_back in the first code can be parallelized."

It's likely that your CPU will agree. Given the data size, this is likely to hit a bottleneck from L3 cache to main memory. Modern CPU cores are capable of out-of-order execution, and this looks like the CPU will happily start with instructions that belong to the second `push_back` while the first one is waiting for main memory. That's exactly why out-of-order execution is a common feature.

The chief problem is reallocation - you didn't reserve capacity. And reallocation is not a simple CPU operation; it requires access to a global heap. I would suggest reserving `128/sizeof(int)` elements per inner vector. That's one or two cache lines on comon CPU's, so you don't have vectors sharing cache lines.

Comment: I think the bottleneck is addressing because my second approach is faster. I think parallel `push_back` can parallel addressing, so maybe it's quicker.

Comment: @HuZhang: Addressing? The address generation on x86 is essentially free (pipelined). Accessing main memory is the slow part, but that's not something you can parallelize.

Comment: But why the second approach is faster?

Comment: @HuZhang: The one with cacheline-sized reservations? It means the two push_backs will operate on separate cache lines., which means the read-modify-write cycle operates independently.